# Why I cant use Ajax in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I started learning Rails 3 months ago.And now I'm trying to add Ajax in my Rails app.

So it have some problems.

In my Index.html.erb file:

```
<script>
    function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET","demo.txt", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">click</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

And I created a file that demo.txt.I try to show content in demo.txt when I click the button.But it shows nothing.

So have any tut for me.

Thanks !

Comment: Please take a look at your JS console. It surely has some errors : `var xhttp =ew XMLHttpRequest();`

Comment: Is there any specific reason you tagged this post with `jQuery`? You don't seem to be using it at all in your example code.

Comment: I'm sorry.I fixed it

Comment: Are there any additional javascript errors on your page? Are you certain that your `loadDoc` function is being called?

Comment: I dont know how to see the javascript errors.Can you tell me what should I do ?

Comment: So how can I fix the JS errors ?

Comment: @HưngHíp: Inspect by your browser, then check the network console!

Comment: @HưngHíp - (in chrome) On windows you can hit `F12`, on Mac it's `Cmd+Alt+i`. Then go to the console tab.

Comment: @HieuPham Anh có thể chỉ em cụ thể được không ?

Comment: @Lix It shows that : GET http://localhost:3000/demo.txt 404 Not Found

Comment: @HưngHíp - Great! Now we are getting closer to the problem! We now know that the AJAX request is being made but the server can not find your `demo.txt` file - that is why the server is returning a `404` error. The next question is: where did you place that file? Is it in the `public` folder of your rails application?

Comment: @Lix The file demo.txt in Vendor

Comment: @HưngHíp - try placing it into the `public` folder in the root of your rails project.

Comment: @Lix Thank you! It worked.I placed it to the public folder

Comment: @HưngHíp - Great! Happy that it worked in the end! Take a look at the answer below - it actually does mention that public folder. You might want to recognise that answer as the most helpful.

Comment: @Lix Sorry I want to ask more question.In the Index file,I write a link to new action,I use remote: true hash.It worked but in the console shows that 304 Not Modified.So is it wrong ?

Comment: @HưngHíp - you might want to open a new post for that question since your original question has been answered already.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of the xhttp.open(...) call should be a URL, not simple a file name.  If you are running the Rails application with "rails s" then your url might look something like "http://localhost:3000/demo.txt" if the file demo.txt is in your public folder.  Without a URL in that second parameter, I suspect that the request is never finding your rails application.

You might also want to dig into jquery (since you tagged it) to understand how to use that library to issue the request.  The interface is much simpler than the low-level js.

Comment: Without the URL protocol it would be resolved as a relative path and it would simply look for the file (as you said) in the public folder. This *should* work - I believe the issue is actually JS error and the request is never actually being made...

Comment: I changed my code xhttp.open("GET","localhost:3000/demo.txt", true);.But it still doesn't show anything